# Laplace Transformations - Introduction

Tags: laplace-transform

We know, that given a function $f(t)$ where $t\geq 0$, its Laplace transform $F(s) = \mathcal{L}{\{f(t)\}}$ is defined as $F(s) = \mathcal{L}{\{f(t)\}} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-st}f(t)dt}$

I am given $f(t) = te^{-t}$ with $t\geq0$. So

$F(s) = \mathcal{L}{\{f(t)\}} = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{0}^{t}{e^{-st}te^{-t}dt}$

The expression within the integrand simplifies to

$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{0}^{t}{e^{-t-st}dt}$

Then I used integration by parts to yeild

$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{{e^{-s-1}t}}{(-s-1)(s+1)}$

Again, parts gives me another limit expressed as

$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{{te^{-s-1}t}}{(s+1)}$

I really do not think I am on the right track with this. Please, if someone would guide me in a more correct direction I can help other people too.

Comment: Too many $t$'s in your formula for $F(s)$: one a dummy variable, the other the upper limit of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Please be careful using $t$ as a variable and as a limit. You want
$$\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_0^T t\mathrm e^{-t}\cdot \mathrm e^{-st}~\mathrm dt$$

I get a different answer when I use integration by parts. I get
$$\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_0^T t\mathrm e^{-t(s+1)}~\mathrm dt \ \ = \ \ \lim_{T\to \infty}\left[-\frac{st+t+1}{s^2+2s+1}\mathrm e^{-(s+1)t} \right]_0^T$$

I'll leave you to try to finish this. Remember to assume that $s>0$.

Comment: Is it $-1$? I have $T$ instead of $t$..So, I just broke up the limits. Evidently, I need to review Calculus I.

Comment: @cryptomath Is what $-1$? Like I said: don't use $t$ as a variable in the integral and a number in the limit. E.g. $\int_0^x x^2~\mathrm dx$ is bad; use a different letter for the limit, e.g. $\int_0^X x^2~\mathrm dx$.